# How to get difference language code for iOS 7 AVSpeechUtterance text to speech?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I want to use iOS 7 new speech synthezis API, and my application is localized in french & english,german,japanese,etc.i want set language code to read text.How to get language code?

```
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-ZA"];
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set one of the bellow language:

```
 for (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice in [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]) {
            NSLog(@" %@", voice.language);
        }
```

or use default locale:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Localized -text"];
 utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate; // Tell it to me slowly
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

update

this is the list with the supported languages:

```
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) - ar-SA
Chinese (China) - zh-CN
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) - zh-HK
Chinese (Taiwan) - zh-TW
Czech (Czech Republic) - cs-CZ
Danish (Denmark) - da-DK
Dutch (Belgium) - nl-BE
Dutch (Netherlands) - nl-NL
English (Australia) - en-AU
English (Ireland) - en-IE
English (South Africa) - en-ZA
English (United Kingdom) - en-GB
English (United States) - en-US
Finnish (Finland) - fi-FI
French (Canada) - fr-CA
French (France) - fr-FR
German (Germany) - de-DE
Greek (Greece) - el-GR
Hebrew (Israel) - he-IL
Hindi (India) - hi-IN
Hungarian (Hungary) - hu-HU
Indonesian (Indonesia) - id-ID
Italian (Italy) - it-IT
Japanese (Japan) - ja-JP
Korean (South Korea) - ko-KR
Norwegian (Norway) - no-NO
Polish (Poland) - pl-PL
Portuguese (Brazil) - pt-BR
Portuguese (Portugal) - pt-PT
Romanian (Romania) - ro-RO
Russian (Russia) - ru-RU
Slovak (Slovakia) - sk-SK
Spanish (Mexico) - es-MX
Spanish (Spain) - es-ES
Swedish (Sweden) - sv-SE
Thai (Thailand) - th-TH
Turkish (Turkey) - tr-TR
```

Comment: ok thank you tonymkenu, how can i identifify voice.language corresponding city or language name

Comment: more info here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/01/08/synthesized-speech-from-text.html

Comment: thank you tonyMkenu...is it possible to add custom lanuguage?

Comment: at least for now... I have not found any clue about that. Glad to help you! :)

Comment: Are there any languages that allow you to chose both male or female voices?

Comment: @JavierQuevedo You can do that by changing the pitch. Male: `utterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.8`, female: `utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.6`

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 3 update:**

```
import AVFoundation
```

(check the languages codes):

```
for voice in (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()){
        print(voice.language)
    }
```

Then:

```
let speakTalk   = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let speakMsg    = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World, I can speak")

speakMsg.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
speakMsg.pitchMultiplier = 1.2
speakMsg.rate   = 0.5

speakTalk.speak(speakMsg)
```